# Excel VBA to copy adjacent column in different sheet based on matching criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro to check sheet1 if the value in column A matches the value in the same column in sheet2, and if so, it copies the adjacent cell for each matched value from sheet1 into sheet2. Below is what I have so far, but I keep getting 'run time error 9' on the lastrowadd line and am not sure why. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
Sub CopyAdjacent()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, colStatus As Long, lastrowAdd As Long, lastrowRemove As Long

    colStatus = 2 'your status column number
    lastrowAdd = Sheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(Sheets(“Sheet1”).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrowRemove = Sheets(“Sheet2”).Cells(Sheets(“Sheet2”).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastrowAdd
        For j = 1 To lastrowRemove
            If Sheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets(“Sheet2”).Cells(j, 1).Value Then
                Sheets(“Sheet2”).Cells(j, colStatus).Value = Sheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(i, colStatus).Value
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(Sheets(“Sheet1”).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` Try changing this to `Sheets(“Sheet1”).Rows.Count-1` and see what happen

Comment: It still gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of small changes have been made including the way both `lastrowAdd` and `lastrowRemove` have been defined. I also removed `i` and `j` from the definition.

```
Sub CopyAdjacent()
Dim colStatus As Long, lastrowAdd As Integer, lastrowRemove As Integer

colStatus = 2
lastrowAdd = Sheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastrowRemove = Sheets(“Sheet2”).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrowAdd
    For j = 1 To lastrowRemove
        If Sheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets(“Sheet2”).Cells(j, 1).Value Then
            Sheets(“Sheet2”).Cells(j, colStatus).Value = Sheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(i, colStatus).Value
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Also this isn't checking if on the same column the two are matching. It checks every column of `Sheet2` against each one from `Sheet1`. I think the below code is what you are looking for.

```
Sub CopyAdjacent()
' The below line has been changed, you may still omit lastrowRemove
Dim colStatus, lastrowAdd, lastrowRemove As Integer

colStatus = 2
lastrowAdd = Sheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
' The below line is now redundant in the new code
'lastrowRemove = Sheets(“Sheet2”).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrowAdd
        If Sheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets(“Sheet2”).Cells(i, 1).Value Then
            Sheets(“Sheet2”).Cells(i, colStatus).Value = Sheets(“Sheet1”).Cells(i, colStatus).Value
        End If    
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I see your point in what you did and i think i have made sense of your changes, but sadly I still get the same error :/

Comment: Does it tell you more specifically where the error is occuring. Runtime Error 9 is for being out of range, are your sheets definitely called `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` or does it give you anything extra? Also try changing `colStatus As Long` to `colStatus As Integer`. That may be it because I think you should only call cell references with integers since you can have cell A1.5

Comment: It still gives the same debugging highlight of that same line lastrowAdd, even when changing colStatus from Long to Integer. Also, my sheets are called Sheet1 and Sheet2.